# I can't move around a loaded SceneKit model

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

Below is the function that loads my object. Whenever I run the app, the object loads perfectly but when I try getting close or moving around, it moves along with the camera. I tried loading using hit test, it works but then collisions do not work when I use hit results and world positioning.

```
func addBackboard() {

    guard let bucketScene = SCNScene(named:"art.scnassets/BucketBlue.scn") else {
        return
    }
    guard let bucketNode = bucketScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "tube", recursively: false) else { 
        return
    }
    bucketNode.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.5, 0.5,  0.5);
    bucketNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: -3.5, z: -5)

    let physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: bucketNode, options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type: SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.concavePolyhedron])
    let physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: physicsShape)
    bucketNode.physicsBody = physicsBody
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(bucketNode)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/aranchor) that might help. Summary: "To track the static positions and orientations of real or virtual objects relative to the camera, create anchor objects and use the `add(anchor:)` method to add them to your AR session."

And then, did you implement the ARSCNViewDelegate methods?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your model's [pivot point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61984938/scnnode-is-not-appearing-in-correct-position/62246640#62246640) is above the ground level (as well as your model). Also, make sure if you've disabled `.allowsCameraControl` or not, in case you're running AR app.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = false       // For AR app use false
        self.addBackboard()
    }    
    private func addBackboard() {            
        guard let scene = SCNScene(named:"BucketBlue.scn") else { return }
        sceneView.scene = scene
    
        let bucketNode = SCNNode()
        bucketNode.geometry = SCNTube()
        bucketNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.5, 0.5,  0.5)
        bucketNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -5)   // Y is zero
    
        let physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(
                          node: bucketNode,
                       options:[SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type:
                                SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.concavePolyhedron])
        let physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, 
                                        shape: physicsShape)
        bucketNode.physicsBody = physicsBody
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(bucketNode)
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        sceneView.session.run(config)
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually it was only the position vector that wasn't correct. I fixed it by changing the Y axis one as it was "below" ground level.