# SCNNode is not appearing in correct position

Tags: swift, xcode, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I downloaded the `wall2.obj` file from Google Blocks and then I used Blender to change the extension to `.dae` the wall node is not appearing where it should be.

Where the wall node placed vs. where it should be placed:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Pivot point's position issue

In Blender change a `pivot point`'s position to the desired one – move pivot point to the center of your model, and then at its bottom. If your model consists of several independent parts, group all parts and use just one [composite pivot point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586205/arkit-pivot-point-of-3d-model-is-wrong/52589495#52589495).

Or you can use `simdPivot` instance property in you code to move a pivot programmatically:

```
brickWallNode.simdPivot.columns.3.x = -0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution for Xcode users is creating a parent node for that object and then move the object node relative to the parent node you have created.

[image: #1]
[image: #2]